# nmap failed to determine route

Tags: networking

I have set about trying to learn nmap, though for some reason it does not work I keep getting the same error, the only time it works is when I specify loopback address, this is the error I get otherwise:

`Premature EOF in /proc/net/route
nexthost: failed to determine route to 192.168.1.1
QUITTING!`

I have checked the file /proc/net/route and found that it is empty. What should I do? I have searched the web and can't find a solution. Since I'm stuck at this hurdle I can't progress in any way learning nmap unfortunately.

EDIT:

This what ifconfig brings up:

```
lo Link encap:Local Loopback inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 
Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1 
RX packets:521137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
TX packets:521137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 
Txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:22075684 (22.0 MB) TX bytes:22075684 (22.0 MB)
```

Comment: This is a general unix networking question, and has nothing to do with `nmap` or security. On that basis, you'll get better answers on unix&linux or superuser.

Comment: Please provide the output of the command ifconfig, I have a slight suspicion you aren't connected to a network.

Comment: this what ifconfig brings up [code]lo       Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:521137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:521137 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:22075684 (22.0 MB)  TX bytes:22075684 (22.0 MB)[/code]

Comment: I'm using a Ubuntu VMware virtual machine.

Comment: I can't switch the tags now unfortunately.

Comment: @user28130 you will need to set up networking in vmware. You probably want a `bridged adapter` or `NAT`, ifconfig should contain `eth0`, yours does not.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't got any network configured, you need to configure a network interface and have working network connection before you can actually start scanning.

Start by configuring your VMware to bridge the network interface to your physical network card or setup a host only network if you have a second virtual machine running a machine you want to scan.